# Python: Chequear Varios Ficheros de Texto

Tags: python, python-3.x

¿Es posible comprobar que los valores obtenidos en un fichero .csv llamado `A` son los mismos que en otro fichero .csv `B` e imprimir los casos diferentes en un fichero salida.txt? Yo he hecho esto:

```
import time

# En primer lugar debemos de abrir el fichero que vamos a leer.
# y abrir el fichero donde vamos a guardar la informacion.
infile = open('Intercambio Modbus v11 - RGA.csv', 'r')
outfile = open("salida.txt","w")
# Mostramos por pantalla lo que leemos desde el fichero
print('>>> Lectura del fichero línea a línea')

# Timer de 2 segundos para probar si funciona, podemos meter timer para que espere unos segundos antes de comprobar una salida.
# time.sleep(2)

for line in infile:
    line = line[:-1]
    split_line = line.split(";")
    if split_line[5] == split_line[11]:
        outfile.write("La línea es correcta\n")
        #time.sleep(3)
    else:
        outfile.write("NO COINCIDEN LOS VALORES --> " + line + "\n")

# Cerramos el fichero.
infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

Con este fichero compruebo los valores que me interesa saber si son iguales dentro del mismo fichero pero....¿Que pasada si en lugar de `split_line[11]` del mismo fichero quisiera comprobar de otro fichero distinto?¿Como puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tus dos ficheros tienen el mismo numero de lineas puedes usar la función preconstruida [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) que retorna un iterador con tuplas formadas por las parejas de dos iterables. Si alguno de los ficheros tiene más lineas que el otro solo se compararán aquellas que tengan pareja en el otro, es decir, las lineas de más no se tienen en cuenta. Sería algo así:

```
import time

# En primer lugar debemos de abrir el fichero que vamos a leer.
# y abrir el fichero donde vamos a guardar la informacion.
infile1 = open('a.csv', 'r')
infile2 = open('b.csv', 'r')
outfile = open("salida.txt","w")
# Mostramos por pantalla lo que leemos desde el fichero
print('>>> Lectura del fichero línea a línea')

# Timer de 2 segundos para probar si funciona, podemos meter timer para que espere unos segundos antes de comprobar una salida.
# time.sleep(2)

for line1, line2 in zip(infile1, infile2):
    line1 = line1[:-1]
    line2 = line2[:-1]

    if line1.split(";")[5] == line2.split(";")[11]:
        outfile.write("La línea es correcta\n")
        #time.sleep(3)
    else:
        outfile.write("NO COINCIDEN LOS VALORES --> " + line1 + "\n")

# Cerramos el fichero.
infile1.close()
infile2.close()
outfile.close()
```

Podrías usar [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) para simplificar si quieres:

```
with open('a.csv') as infile1, open('b.csv') as infile2, open('salida.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line1, line2 in zip(infile1, infile2):
        line1 = line1[:-1]
        line2 = line2[:-1]

        if line1.split(";")[5] == line2.split(";")[11]:
            outfile.write("La línea es correcta\n")
        else:
            outfile.write("NO COINCIDEN LOS VALORES --> " + line1 + "\n")
```

Si trabajas a menudo con archivos csv te recomiendo que mires el módulo [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) que pertenece a la biblioteca estandar de Python y facilita la lectura/escritura de este tipo de archivos.

Comment: El fichero no funciona del todo bien, creo que se esta haciendo un lío con caracteres especiales. Cuando llega a esta línea: D12022;12022;40021;9C55;Inf. Veh¡culo: Posici¢n;1;D13022;13022;30021;7545;Restringido -  Clonar;0 Se hace un lío y creo que puede ser por los espacios. ¿Sabrías como puedo hacer que no tengo en cuenta los espacios? Muchas gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: @AlberM puedes eliminar los espacios de una cadena mediante el método de cadena `replace()`. Por ejemplo, `>>> cadena = 'Soy una cadena '`,  `>>> cadena.replace(' ', '')`, `>>> print(cadena)`, `>>> Soyunacadena` – FJSevilla hace 28 min

Comment: De todas formas si solo estas comparando no deberia darte problemas, ¿te tira algún errror o es que no hace bién la comparación

Comment: parece que ahora funciona correctamente en ambos casos. ¿Sabes como puedo hacer que este en constante vigilancia de ambos ficheros? No solo ejecutar la "macro" y obtener las diferencias sino que esté comprobando constantemente y cuando se produzca alguna modificación en A que no cuadre en B pues se imprima en el fichero la diferencia con la fecha y hora.

Comment: @AlberM lo  sencillo sería hacer esto mismo cada cierto tiempo(un ciclo infinito y un delay con `time.sleep()`),  no obstante esto es ineficiente si quieres actualizacionse cada pocos segundos. Otra opción seria usar por ejemplo `os.stat()` para ver cuando alguno de los ficheros es modificado y entonces comparar. Si puedes/quieres puedes usar [`wathdog`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog) que es muy útil para monitorizar archivos. Depende mucho de como se generen esos csv, es dificil(y no de debe) contestar por aquí, si tienes dudas puedes hacer otra pregunta o ir al chat y hablar por él.