# Python error de atributo en Split

Tags: python

Alguien sabe por que me aparece en el siguiente código:

> ERROR en line 6 "tuple" object has no attribute 'split'

El código es el siguiente:

```
import time

with open('FicheroEntrada.csv') as infile1, open('Diferencias.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line1 in zip(infile1):
        #Busco en el fichero la línea que me interesa.
        if line1.split(";")[4] == "Valor Byte Semaforo":
            #Después de 5 segundos voy a comprobar como esta el valor en el fichero de salida.
            time.sleep(2)
            #Comparo el valor del fichero de entrada con el valor esperado en el fichero de salida.
            with open('FicheroSalida.csv') as infile2:
                for line2 in zip(infile2):
                    if line2.split(";")[11] != line1.split(";")[11]:
                        outfile.write( time.strftime("%H:%M:%S") + "  Valor Byte Semaforo (no hay coincidencia).\n")
                        outfile.write( time.strftime("%H:%M:%S") + "  --> Valor Esperado: " + line1.split(";")[11])
                        outfile.write( time.strftime("%H:%M:%S") + "  --> Valor Obtenido: " + line2.split(";")[11])
                        outfile.write( "--------------------------------------------\n")
                    else:
                        #Mensaje para indicar que las pruebas no tiene errores.
                        outfile.write("No hay errores en las pruebas!!!\n")

#Cerramos ficheros          
infile1.close()
infile2.close()
outfile.close()
```

No se como solucionarlo. Lo unico que pretendo es abrir un segundo fichero y comprobar si una cadena es igual a la segunda cadena.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que tu confusión puede venir de mi respuesta en [otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34991/python-chequear-varios-ficheros-de-texto) de tus preguntas. [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) retorna un iterador que contiene tuplas de parejas formadas tomando elementos de dos iterables por orden, seria mas claro con un ejemplo usando dos listas:

```
lista1 = ['Hola', 'Adios', 'Saludos']
lista2 = ['Pedro', 'Juan', 'Maria']
print(*zip(lista1, lista2))
```

Nos retorna:

```
('Hola', 'Pedro') ('Adios', 'Juan') ('Saludos', 'Maria')
```

Yo lo usaba para obtener las parejas de lineas de dos archivos distintos:

```
with open('a.csv') as infile1, open('b.csv') as infile2:
    for line1, line2 in zip(infile1, infile2):
```

En tu caso como solo abres un fichero debes eliminar la función `zip`

Por otro lado no es necesario que cierrres tus archivos si usas `with`, esa es una de las ventajas de usarlo con arhivos, cuando se termina la ejecución el archivo se cierra automáticamente sin tener que llamar a `.close()`:

El código deberia quedar así:

```
import time

with open('FicheroEntrada.csv') as infile1, open('Diferencias.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line1 in infile1:
        #Busco en el fichero la línea que me interesa.
        if line1.split(";")[4] == "Valor Byte Semaforo":
            #Después de 5 segundos voy a comprobar como esta el valor en el fichero de salida.
            time.sleep(2)
            #Comparo el valor del fichero de entrada con el valor esperado en el fichero de salida.
            with open('FicheroSalida.csv') as infile2:
                for line2 in infile2:
                    if line2.split(";")[11] != line1.split(";")[11]:
                        outfile.write( time.strftime("%H:%M:%S") + "  Valor Byte Semaforo (no hay coincidencia).\n")
                        outfile.write( time.strftime("%H:%M:%S") + "  --> Valor Esperado: " + line1.split(";")[11])
                        outfile.write( time.strftime("%H:%M:%S") + "  --> Valor Obtenido: " + line2.split(";")[11])
                        outfile.write( "--------------------------------------------\n")
                    else:
                        #Mensaje para indicar que las pruebas no tiene errores.
                        outfile.write("No hay errores en las pruebas!!!\n")
```

Ten en cuenta que lo que estas haciendo es comparar cada linea de `infile1` con todas las lineas de `infile2`. Es decir para la 1ª linea de `infile1` la comparas con la 1ª, la 2º, la 3º, la 4º, etc de `infile2` y asi con todas. Si lo que quieres es comparar la 1ª linea de `infile1` solo con la linea que le pertenece de `infile2`, la 2º linea con su pareja en `infile2`, etc entoces tendrias que modificar el código.

Answer (score 0):

El problema viene con el uso de `zip` en la línea `for line2 in zip(infile2):`. El `zip` te devuelve una tupla y por eso `line2` es una tupla y no dispone de método `split` ya que no es de tipo *string*.

Comment: ¿Y por que no me da el mismo fallo para line1? ¿Sabrías como rehacer bien el fichero?

Comment: en el bucle para `line1` no haces uso de `zip`. Sin tener mucho tiempo para mirar el código creo que quitando el `zip` en el segundo bucle debería funcionar.